# Web Application design - Dealing with complex data

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, codeigniter, backbone.js

I'm building an internal application which shows the skills and skillsets of our employees. However, I have trouble dealing with the huge amount of data that goes into this. I'm not sure if I'm doing this the right way and I would really like some feedback.

I wanted to create the API in Rails and build on top of that with Backbone.js as I thought it would be a good learning experience and as I want it to be a very responsive and fluid, these technologies seemed fit.

However, since I'm dealing with a lot of data here, I couldn't quite get it done in Rails. I kind of got stuck on recreating the database schema I had in mind through my models and model relationships.

Perhaps it's a good idea to post the DB schema here, since it's quite an important part of this question:

```
employee            skill             skillset            department
--------            ------            --------            ----------
id                  id                id                  id
name                name              name                name
firstname
description
email
departmentid


departmenthasskillset               employeehasskill
---------------------               ----------------
departmentid                        employeeid
skillsetid                          skillid 
                                    rating

skillsethasskill
----------------
skillsetid
skillid
```

I have since started over in PHP/CodeIgniter, however I don't really like the approach I took and I would really like to start with this in Rails/Backbone. Is there a way to do these complex queries in Rails/ActiveRecord and how would I tackle this best?

On my frontpage, I show all the employees and I'm able to filter through them based on department, skill and skillset with the isotope.js plugin. This also means I need to load a lot of data on the first request. I have put all of this data in one huge array for now, like this for one employee:

```
[51] => Array
    (
        [id] => 51
        [name] => Name
        [firstname] => Firstname
        [description] => Multimedia developer
        [email] => firstname.name@company.com
        [departmentid] => 9
        [skills] => Array
            (
                [html] => 3
                [css] => 3
                [javascript] => 3
                [jquery] => 3
                [php] => 2
            )

        [skillsets] => Array
            (
                [1] => frontend
                [2] => backend
            )

        [department] => development
        [class] => html css javascript jquery php frontend backend development
    )
```

(The 'class' index is needed for Isotope so I can filter.)

Is this a decent approach (loading all the data in one HUGE array), and would I be able to get this done in Rails? Or would it be better to make separate requests for different data?

Any feedback is welcome, as I still haven't decided if I'll continue working on this in PHP or switch back to Rails for another attempt. The whole thing just feels clumsy at the moment and I can't say I really enjoy working on it at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your still thinking too much like a php coder. You didnt attend the conventions rails gives. You named foreign keys like this: `employeeid` but it should be `employee_id` this is really important because you dont build sql queries manually like you do in php. For exanmple in your `employeehasskill` model you need to add the following lines:

```
belongs_to :employee
belongs_to :skill
```

So in your `employee` and your `skill` model you need to add

```
has_many :employeehasskills
```

And in your `employee` model you should also add:

```
has_many :skills, :through => :employeehasskills
```

This is the way you define relations in rails. Its important to respect the conventions because if you say `belongs_to :employee` rails by default awaits that your foreign key is `employee_id`. This will enable you to do the following:

```
e=Employee.find(<the id here>)
e.skills
```

That would return the skills of the employee. This is a quit different approach to php but its worth learning it. I would suggest you to read the official documentation of ActiveRecord: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: Are there conventions on naming tables in rails? I mean, 'employeehasskills' sounds really crappy. I'll definitely check out the documentation and perhaps try this again. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah that true! If you use the scaffolder what you should do the tables will automaticle be named in pluraliozation of the models name! I would suggest you to read the documentation about scaffolder first!